# How to get modified and original geojson points after editing polygon in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a geojson feature I've created. After editing, I know there is a draw:edited event. How do I get the original points that the polygon consisted of, and is it possible to get the new polygon points? How? Is it possible to know which vertices were changed or added?

I tried the following, all of which does not work:

```
map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
  var type = e.layerType;
  var layer = e.layer; // this is giving undefined errors

  var shape = layer.toGeoJSON() // this is undefined
  var shape_for_db = JSON.stringify(shape);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `draw:created` event fired on `L.Map` returns a `L.LayerGroup` as `e.layers`, which contains all the features that just have been edited. This is because you can edit multiple features at once before pressing the save button. You can iterate the `L.LayerGroup` and then fetch the GeoJSON:

```
map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
    e.layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        console.log(layer.toGeoJSON());
    });
});
```